# Hibernate + Oracle IN clause limitation, how to solve it?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I know this question is posted many times, but I want to ask about details,

Using Oracle, you can't pass to IN clause more than 1000 parameters, so using hibernate with oracle may have some solutions to this issue like:

1- use OR clause between IN clause for each 1000 Parameters list, but this isn't applicable due to the other limitation by oracle for the whole query parameters not to exceed 2000

2- use a for loop, to run the query in term of 1000 parameters list each time, and then append all the results, this is not very good if you need sorting, or using criteria api with different level modification

3- put the parameters list in a temp physical table, and join it, or even use it in a sub criteria, and this solution I can't try, because I don't know how to create a temp table using hibernate, and then use it,

so if any other thoughts available using CRITERIA api please share it, or even if there's a simple way to handle solution number '3'

Regards,

Comment: can you post an example of a query that results in more than 1000 values in the IN clause?

Comment: you can consider any query like selecting 2000 records from a table, or even passing a list of 2000 parameters as an input, I don't think it's a problem

Comment: when are you in need of passing 2000 parameters as an input? sounds like a code smell to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of, the fact that you need to pass more than 2000 ids (judging by your 1st point) to a query is a warning bell in and of itself. Perhaps there's a better way of solving the underlying problem.

You can use approach #2 and sort each list, then perform mergesort within the application. That will require extra code, but will likely (assuming the actual query is relatively fast) perform better than approach #3.

For #3, there are 2 big downsides to dealing with temporary tables:

- while Hibernate does support them (look at `Table.sqlTemporaryTableCreateString` method, it uses a bunch of supporting methods in the `Dialect` class), they're used internally and will require additional coding on your part to be accessible from the app.
- more importantly, using a temporary table will force you to write your query as native SQL (since it's not going to be mapped). If you're using Criteria API you will have to use  `sqlRestriction` with a subquery.

Comment: I think you are totally right, but could you help me with this, is there any way to edit a criteria before running it, as the criteria is passed through several methods which add restrictions to it, and at the end I want to be able to check these restrictions before running it

Comment: @Amr - no, you won't be able to edit Criteria instance, at least not without resorting to dirty tricks with reflection. Criteria API is pretty much write-only.

Answer (score 3):

With a little help of Guava Lists and Hibernate Disjunction:

```
    Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
    for (List<?> chunkList: Lists.partition(largeList, 1000)) {
        disjunction.add(Restrictions.in(propertyName, chunkList));
    }
    criteria.add(disjunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in Java, the best option to do it is making sublists of the main list and then use it in the query:

```
int DBLIMIT = 2000;
int MAXRESULTS = 1999;
int valueResults = 0;
if (list.size() > DBLIMIT) {
    while (valueResults >= 0) {
    List<String> listMAXRESULTSReg= new ArrayList<>();
    if ((list.size() - (listMAXRESULTSReg.size() + MAXRESULTS * (valueResults + 1))) > 0) {
        listMAXRESULTSReg = list.subList(MAXRESULTS * valueResults, MAXRESULTS * (valueResults + 1));
        valueResults++;
    } else if ((list.size() - (listMAXRESULTSReg.size() + MAXRESULTS * (valueResults + 1))) <= 0) {
        listMAXRESULTSReg = list.subList(MAXRESULTS * valueResults, list.size() - 1);
        valueResults = -1;
    }
    String queryStr = "FROM table" + "WHERE field in (:field) ";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr).setParameter("field", listMAXRESULTSReg);
    resultList.addAll(query.getResultList());
}
return resultList;
```

Hope it help you.