# Disable merging of similar predicates in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

My problem starts in fact that oracle supports only 1000 elements in in(...) predicate. So executing query similar to

```
select * from table where column in ({2000 elements});
```

will result in exception. Some googling got me idea of dividing elements in multiple predicates with 1000 elements like this:

```
select * from table where column in ({1000 elements}) or column in ({1000 elements});
```

This works excellent when query is executed directly, but when I am using Hibernate session.createSQLQuery() it results in one 'in' predicate with all the elements and i get exception from database.

Is there any way to disable this optimization or any other workaround?
I am using Hibernate 3.2.6 and this is legacy project.

Comment: Check out this previous stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758198/hibernate-oracle-in-clause-limitation-how-to-solve-it

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for pointing me to other question. Solved my question